# Ext JS – Disabling FormPanel submit if validation fails

Tags: regex, validation, extjs, textarea, disable

I am not able to disable the button on form validation fails. I want to use regex: `/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$/` for text area validation. I want to disable `activatebutton`.

I tried `formBind` and monitor validate still not working.

**Here is the code:**

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    items: [{
        columnWidth: .75,
        layout: "form",
        monitorValid: true,
        items: {
            fieldLabel: 'Please Enter  Activation Id',
            name: 'Activate',
            xtype: 'textarea',
            msgTarget: 'under',
            growMax: 200,
            allowBlank: false,
            blankText: "Please Enter Comma separated AssetIds",
            regex: /^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$/,
            anchor: '100%'
        }
    }, {
        columnWidth: .25,
        items: {
            xtype: 'button',
            name: 'button',
            id: 'activatebutton',
            width: 100,
            text: 'Set for auto-activation',
            formBind: true,
            listeners: {
                click: function () {
                    shared.Notifier.success('The requ  ');
                    this.seForActivation();
                },
                scope: this
            }
        }
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `formBind` to work, you need to have an `Ext.form.Panel`.
The form panel will process the checks of the form fields and call the `formBind` when the whole form is valid.

The following code will propcess the `formBind`, see also the [working Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2p31) and the [Ext.form.Panel documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html).

```
{
    xtype: 'form',
    layout: 'column',
    items: [{
        columnWidth: .75,
        layout: "form",
        monitorValid: true,

        items: {
            fieldLabel: 'Please Enter  Activation Id',
            name: 'Activate',
            xtype: 'textarea',
            msgTarget: 'under',
            growMax: 200,
            allowBlank: false,
            blankText: "Please Enter Comma separated AssetIds",
            regex: /^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$/,
            anchor: '100%'

        }
    }, {
        columnWidth: .25,
        items: {
            xtype: 'button',
            name: 'button',

            id: 'activatebutton',
            width: 100,
            text: 'Set for auto-activation',
            formBind: true,
            listeners: {
                click: function () {

                    shared.Notifier.success('The requ  ');
                    this.seForActivation();
                },
                scope: this
            }
        }
    }]
```